# Do not read directories after 3 level using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, callback

Is there any way to stop reading directory after specific point or 3 level tree structure

for example

```
MainFolder
-ABC Folder
-DEF Folder
-GHI Folder
-image.png
-jkl.gif
```

when i click on ABC folder my path will look like this `/MainFolder/ABC Folder`
if there is any other folder or file in it then it will look like

```
/MainFolder/ABC Folder
-PQR Folder
-STU Folder
-abc.pdf
-xyz.txt
```

click on PQR folder then it will look like this

```
/MainFolder/ABC Folder/PQR Folder
-DFC Folder
-HKJ Folder
-mnb.pdf
-xyz.txt
```

but it should not read DFC Folder/HKJ Folder or any other folder which are present after 3level tree structure
Output :-

```
["MainFolder/image.png",
"MainFolder/jkl.gif",
"MainFolder/ABC Folder/abc.pdf",
"MainFolder/ABC Folder/xyz.txt",
"MainFolder/ABC Folder/PQR Folder/mnb.pdf",
"MainFolder/ABC Folder/PQR Folder/xyz.txt"]
```

code which i have it read all files and sub directories but i want to stop at 3level directory

```
async function getAllFile(folderPath) {
  let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        return getAllFile(filePath);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    })
  );

  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}
```

PS : using node 10.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. I added the depth parameter, which basically stands for how many folder levels you will want to traverse. In the case of your file tree, you would call this function with depth 2: `getAllFile('./MainFolder/', 2)` as you want to explore the root (level 1) and the subfolders (level 2), but not the folders within the subfolders (level 3).

I also return null if a folder remains unexplored, as this would otherwise result in `undefined` values. Before returning I filter out these `null` values.

```
async function getAllFile(folderPath, depth) {
  depth -= 1;
  let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory() && depth > 0) {
        return getAllFile(filePath, depth);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
      else return null;
    })
  );
  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []).filter(e => e != null);
}
```

Comment: its not working @fravolt still reading all the folder

Comment: The root does not count towards the depth. A depth of (say) 0 shouldn't return the content of the sub-folders, whereas a depth of 1 should return the subfolders, but not the sub-subfolders. I updated my original answer and included code I can run

Comment: @fravolt "Note that for me the fs.readdir and fs.stat functions don't return, but expect a callback function instead, but this may be a version mismatch on my end (I'm on Node V12.18.3)." - You can use `require('fs').promises` on Node v12 to get access to the promisified versions of the `fs` methods.

Comment: @fravolt i tried your code but still i am getting the directories but thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @Aakash I just put a new and better solution. I tested this myself with your folder structure and it seems to work as expected. Please let me know if it works! :D

Comment: Thank You @fravolt code is working fine now